# Can i create fake response for testing component in cakephp?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I wrote component in cakephp for check response code from url if status code 200 = ok and other code for other case. So if i will testing by PHPUnit test, Can i create fake response(not use real url) that can response status code for testing function in my component. Please help me to solve this problem.

thank.

Comment: Look at the cores tests for the components, you need to mock the response object.

Comment: @burzum i don't clear, could you give me any example.